# Move values from variable one row (in this case year) down and create NA for "new created value"

Tags: r

I have the following df:

```
car <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE, year = c(2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013), 
              person = c("A","A","A","A","A","A", "B","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","C"),
              car = c("BMW", "BMW", "AUDI", "AUDI", "AUDI", "Mercedes", "Citroen","Citroen", "Citroen", "Toyota", "Toyota", "Peugeot", "Volkswagen", "Volkswagen","Volkswagen","Mercedes", "Mercedes","Tesla"))



  # A tibble: 18 x 3
    year person car       
   <dbl> <chr>  <chr>     
 1  2010 A      BMW       
 2  2011 A      BMW       
 3  2012 A      AUDI      
 4  2013 A      AUDI      
 5  2014 A      AUDI      
 6  2015 A      Mercedes  
 7  2013 B      Citroen   
 8  2014 B      Citroen   
 9  2015 B      Citroen   
10  2016 B      Toyota    
11  2017 B      Toyota    
12  2018 B      Peugeot   
13  2008 C      Volkswagen
14  2009 C      Volkswagen
15  2010 C      Volkswagen
16  2011 C      Mercedes  
17  2012 C      Mercedes  
18  2013 C      Tesla
```

I would like to create a variable which shows for each person which car they had previous year, so like this:

```
car <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE, year = c(2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013), 
                  person = c("A","A","A","A","A","A", "B","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","C"),
                  car = c("BMW", "BMW", "AUDI", "AUDI", "AUDI", "Mercedes", "Citroen","Citroen", "Citroen", "Toyota", "Toyota", "Peugeot", "Volkswagen", "Volkswagen","Volkswagen","Mercedes", "Mercedes","Tesla"),
                  previous_year_car = c(NA_real_,"BMW", "BMW", "AUDI", "AUDI", "AUDI", NA_real_, "Citroen","Citroen", "Citroen", "Toyota", "Toyota", NA_real_, "Volkswagen","Volkswagen","Volkswagen","Mercedes", "Mercedes"))



 # A tibble: 18 x 4
    year person car        previous_year_car
   <dbl> <chr>  <chr>      <chr>            
 1  2010 A      BMW        NA               
 2  2011 A      BMW        BMW              
 3  2012 A      AUDI       BMW              
 4  2013 A      AUDI       AUDI             
 5  2014 A      AUDI       AUDI             
 6  2015 A      Mercedes   AUDI             
 7  2013 B      Citroen    NA               
 8  2014 B      Citroen    Citroen          
 9  2015 B      Citroen    Citroen          
10  2016 B      Toyota     Citroen          
11  2017 B      Toyota     Toyota           
12  2018 B      Peugeot    Toyota           
13  2008 C      Volkswagen NA               
14  2009 C      Volkswagen Volkswagen       
15  2010 C      Volkswagen Volkswagen       
16  2011 C      Mercedes   Volkswagen       
17  2012 C      Mercedes   Mercedes         
18  2013 C      Tesla      Mercedes
```

Then of course, for first year of all the persons, the value is NA, as there is no data available from 2009. How do i do code this?

When i do this, it does not reset at a new person:

```
car <- car  %>% transform(car, previous_year_car = c(NA, head(car, -1)))
```

It gives me this:

```
# A tibble: 18 x 5
    year person car        previous_year_car c..BMW....BMW....AUDI....AUDI....AUDI....Mercedes....Citroen...
   <dbl> <chr>  <chr>      <chr>             <chr>                                                          
 1  2010 A      BMW        NA                BMW                                                            
 2  2011 A      BMW        BMW               BMW                                                            
 3  2012 A      AUDI       BMW               AUDI                                                           
 4  2013 A      AUDI       AUDI              AUDI                                                           
 5  2014 A      AUDI       AUDI              AUDI                                                           
 6  2015 A      Mercedes   AUDI              Mercedes                                                       
 7  2013 B      Citroen    Mercedes          Citroen                                                        
 8  2014 B      Citroen    Citroen           Citroen                                                        
 9  2015 B      Citroen    Citroen           Citroen                                                        
10  2016 B      Toyota     Citroen           Toyota                                                         
11  2017 B      Toyota     Toyota            Toyota                                                         
12  2018 B      Peugeot    Toyota            Peugeot                                                        
13  2008 C      Volkswagen Peugeot           Volkswagen                                                     
14  2009 C      Volkswagen Volkswagen        Volkswagen                                                     
15  2010 C      Volkswagen Volkswagen        Volkswagen                                                     
16  2011 C      Mercedes   Volkswagen        Mercedes                                                       
17  2012 C      Mercedes   Mercedes          Mercedes                                                       
18  2013 C      Tesla      Mercedes          Tesla                                                          
>
```

It does not reset when the person changes, i do not know how to change this. It should be that for the first year of a person, the value is NA.

Answer (score 1):

You can `group_by` and use `lag` like in the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
car %>%
  group_by(person) %>%
  mutate(previous_year_car =  lag(car))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 18 × 4
# Groups:   person [3]
    year person car        previous_year_car
   <dbl> <chr>  <chr>      <chr>            
 1  2010 A      BMW        NA               
 2  2011 A      BMW        BMW              
 3  2012 A      AUDI       BMW              
 4  2013 A      AUDI       AUDI             
 5  2014 A      AUDI       AUDI             
 6  2015 A      Mercedes   AUDI             
 7  2013 B      Citroen    NA               
 8  2014 B      Citroen    Citroen          
 9  2015 B      Citroen    Citroen          
10  2016 B      Toyota     Citroen          
11  2017 B      Toyota     Toyota           
12  2018 B      Peugeot    Toyota           
13  2008 C      Volkswagen NA               
14  2009 C      Volkswagen Volkswagen       
15  2010 C      Volkswagen Volkswagen       
16  2011 C      Mercedes   Volkswagen       
17  2012 C      Mercedes   Mercedes         
18  2013 C      Tesla      Mercedes
```